# How do you parse or save data from or to json files with c++?

Tags: c++, json

I'm currently trying to gain some experience in coding with c++. I've already done some projects in other languages such as c# and other but I quickly realized that stuff is done quite different and that I got a lot to learn before I can start programming some more advanced projects.
However, I'm quite experienced in reading and writing data storing file formats such as json or csv (I already succeeded in writing to a csv file in c++ tho). But as it turns out it seems like you can't just work with json files in c++ as easy as you may know it from other programming languages.

**I'd like to know if there are more common ways to create some easily accessable storage files that work in a similar way?**

(For better understanding:)

As I already mentioned, I am aware that c++ is quite different from c# and a lot more difficult to learn because of its advanced syntax. I also worked on a beginning Project (which I thought would be possible to code) for a few hours where I want to log into some "accounts" whose (encrypted) login credentials are stored in a Json file (so I don't really think a code sample is necessary in this case). On the Internet I could find a lot of tutorials teaching how to work with simple text files, but I don't think that's gonna work for me because I plan to work with structured information formats that are easy to navigate. After watching a few tutorials and reading a lot of stackoverflow pages, I decided to ask myself. Thanks for your Help!

Comment: Working with JSON in C++ is basically the same "difficulty" as in other languages, you just need a good parser library. I guess you're confused because there isn't one in the standard library?

Comment: There's no c++ standard implementation for json data parsing (yet). You may use a trusted 3rd party library like nlohnann-json meanwhile.

Comment: JSON would be my choice of formats if working from javascript, since it is JavaScript Object Notation. Working from c++ however, using this data format makes little to no sense to me. I'd either use the XML text format, design a binary one or use something simple like sqlite. In the past I simply read/wrote XML files since they're simply structured and easily edited by hand.

Comment: CSV, DSV for non-hierarchical, xml or yaml for hierarchical - or binary, as mentioned above, or a json parser library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you perceive other languages "simpler" to work with JSON is because those languages have built in class libraries to deal with JSON or they provide a near seamless dependency management framework that lets you very easily choose a 3rd party class library for the task.
The C++ standard makes very little assumptions of the environment that will run the code and thus has a much more limited set of "built in" libraries. And even the word "built in" is a bit of a stretch in the case of C++, since you can make a perfectly decent C++ compiler without providing most of the standard template library. In managed languages like C# or Java we tend to blur the line between "language", "class libraries" and "runtime" and even the build system, so when we encounter a language that has a much clearer distinction between these concepts, we are surprised.

Having said that, googling around a bit, you will find plenty of json parsing libraries for C++.
I recommend trying out Niels Lohmann's json library. I have absolutely NO intention on implying that it is the "best" or "fastest" or "easiest" or anything of the sorts.
Why I would recommend it is that you only have to include the header file and don't have to install and link to dlls, static or dynamic libraries, etc... Which is convenient if you only want a simple project without getting involved more deeply in building and linking and so on. But as I said earlier there are other solutions as well.